# Getting a constructor error in processing

Tags: constructor, undefined, processing

I'm playing with processing from some days, but I encountered an error that i didn't understand. I declared the class and the constructor with the proper arguments, maybe you can help me. This is the code:

```
Cell[][] grid;
int rnc = 5;
int side = 5;
void setup(){
  size(rnc*side,rnc*side);
  grid = new Cell[rnc][rnc];
  for(int i = 0; i < rnc; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < rnc; j++){
      grid[i][j] = new Cell(i,j);
      rect(grid[i][j].row*side,grid[i][j].column*side,side,side);
    }
  }
}
void draw(){}
class Cell
{
  boolean isChecked;
  int row,column;
  int side;
  void Cell(int trow, int tcolumn){
    row=trow;
    column=tcolumn;
}
  void toggleCheck(){
    if(isChecked == true){
      isChecked = false;
    }else{
      isChecked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The error I got after i tried to ran the program is : The constructor sketch.Cell(int,int) is undefined.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which language is this? C#? Java?

Comment: It's http://processing.org, which is based on Java

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is Java, although you haven't specified a language. If so, this is the problem:

```
void Cell(int trow, int tcolumn){
    row=trow;
    column=tcolumn;
}
```

That's not a constructor. That's a method called `Cell`, with a `void` return type. You meant:

```
Cell(int trow, int tcolumn){
    row=trow;
    column=tcolumn;
}
```

(Or possibly `public Cell(...)`.)

At that point, you should be okay. Note that this would have been a *compile-time* error - not an *execution-time* error. Don't try to run your code until it compiles.

Also, it's not clear why you've made your constructor parameters `trow` and `tcolumn` - what's the `t` meant to be for? I'd also make your variables private, and `final` if possible, and simplify your `toggleCheck` method. For example:

```
public final class Cell {

    private final int row, column;
    private boolean checked;
    // It's not clear what side was for

    public Cell(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public void toggleChecked() {
        checked = !checked;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is http://processing.org, which is based on Java.  The Processing environment doesn't have a separate "compile" step; running the "sketch" compiles & runs it.  I confirmed that removing void (as mentioned toward the start of this answer) solves the problem and allows the sketch to run.